# Java compiler forcing raw use of paramatized interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I'm trying to implement a generic interface with concrete types, but the java compiler is forcing me to instantiate it as raw. This is a mock-up of my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("thing", "extra");
    Worker<String, String> worker = new Worker<>();
    worker.execute(map);
}

public class Worker<K, V> {
    public void execute(Map<K, V> map) {
        IDao<K, V> dao = new Dao();
        dao.doThing(map);
    }
}

public interface IDao<K, V> {
    void doThing(Map<K, V> map);
}

public class Dao implements IDao<String, String> {
    public void doThing(Map<String, String> map) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String newKey = key.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(newKey + " " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

This code works as expected if I change `IDao<K, V> dao = new Dao();` to `IDao dao = new Dao()`, but this isn't good practice and I'd like to avoid it. I don't understand why it's illegal to declare the types at instantiation like this.

Comment: So, `Dao` must have a `Map` of `<String, String>`, but `Worker` allows for any generic type - you violating the conditions right there

Comment: I changed it and now it's telling me that Worker and Dao have duplicate type parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This...

```
public class Worker<K, V> {
    public void execute(Map<K, V> map) {
        IDao<K, V> dao = new Dao();
        dao.doThing(map);
    }
}
```

seems wrong to me.

The `Worker` class allows for generic key/value parameters for the `Map`, but, you're instantiating an instance of `Dao` which is constrained to `<String, String>`.  This seems like a basic violation of the contract.

Personally, I might change this so that the instance of `IDao` is injected into the worker, for example...

```
public static class Worker<K, V> {
    
    private IDao<K, V> dao;

    public Worker(IDao<K, V> dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public void execute(Map<K, V> map) {
        dao.doThing(map);
    }
}
```

*nb: This could be an `abstract` factory, which had a `abstract` method something like `abstract protected IDao<K, V> getDao();` and then you'd have to provide some kind concrete implementation to support it, but it's basically boiling down to the same thing*

Then you'd simply be able to call it doing something like...

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("thing", "extra");
Worker<String, String> worker = new Worker<>(new Dao());
worker.execute(map);
```

Of course, if you didn't want to do that, then you'd have to remove the generic constraints for `Worker` and require that any caller pass it a `Map` constrained to `<String, String>`

```
public static class Worker {
    public void execute(Map<String, String> map) {
        IDao<String, String> dao = new Dao();
        dao.doThing(map);
    }
}
```

But now, where's the benefit?

Comment: That's really interesting that it will work as long as you inject the Dao object into the Worker class. I think that solves the issue.

Comment: That fact is, you need to follow the constraints.  You could, just as easily pass it through the `execute` method, `public void execute(IDao<K, V> dao, Map<K, V> map) {` but which you choose will come down to your requirements

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Generics are not very intuitive to me. I wasn't even sure if what I was trying was to do was possible at all because in the implementation, it requires a String to work and I thought it would just treat each map entry as an Object because type information was erased.

Comment: At runtime, that is true, but generics provide compile time protection ... because, developers are awesome 